# How to set a multi-line text to a field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a value of multiple lines, gotten from php and because of the way the textareas are structured, I can't use the standard way to insert it into that textarea. So I was using jQuery to insert it, until now, it throws an error. What is the way to get around it, if any without having to modify the text? I've looked at many places but no luck..

```
$('textarea[name="data_form[question_79]"]').val('Hello member,
Some following messages goes on and on...');
```

Comment: What's the error ? Can we see more code ? Maybe a fiddle ?

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" taken from Google Chrome

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Make sure you don't have a line break in the code

Comment: Or any characters that would break the string, for example a quote.

Comment: yeah, I have linebreaks on the text, and on some cases there are multiple linebreaks, since its text field taken from database, is there any way to get it working with linebreaks?

Comment: The multi-line text is breaking the code: http://jsfiddle.net/VndBp/ (see console for error)

Comment: Can you store these multi-line values as a variable, then add them that way?

Comment: A solution would be to encode the text to JSON and use JSON.parse.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

HTML:

```
<textarea name="data_form[question_79]"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$('textarea[name="data_form[question_79]"]').val('Hello member, Some following messages goes on and on...\n\nthis is a new line');
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/sCrqB/